# Unit test find is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, find, karma-jasmine

When running the unit test on an array I am getting an error `this.sourceAccounts.find is not a function`

component.ts:

```
sourceAccounts: Array<IObject>;
nameChangedSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

ngOnInit() {
        this.nameChangedSubscription =
            this.accountService.accountNameUpdated$.subscribe((newName) => {
                const account = this.sourceAccounts.find(
                    (acc) => newName.accountId === acc.id
                );
                if (account) {
                    account.name = newName.newAccountName;
                }
            });
    }
```

Unit test:

```
describe('MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent', () => {
    let component: MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent>;

    let source_accounts;

    const mockAccountService = {
        accountNameUpdated$: of({
            accountId: '123465',
            newAccountName: 'name',
        }),
    };

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent,
            ],
            imports: [
                TranslateModule.forRoot(),
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule,
                IonicModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: AccountService,
                    useValue: mockAccountService,
                },
            ],
        }).compileComponents();

        source_accounts = [
            {
                id: 'USD3041',
                name: 'Deposit_Account1',
                balance: 'US$ 482,610.41 cr',
                accountno: '00003041',
                currency: {
                    id: 'USD',
                    symbol: 'US$',
                },
            },
            {
                id: 'GBP4041',
                name: 'Current_Account4',
                balance: '£ 482.00 cr',
                accountno: '00005041',
                currency: {
                    id: 'GBP',
                    symbol: '£',
                },
            },
        ] as Array<IObject>;

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(
            MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent
        );

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts[0];

        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts[0];
```

to

```
component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts;
```

And it should hopefully fix the issue. In order to use `.find`, it needs to be an array and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

In Unit test line

```
component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts[0];
```

assigns an object to array property 'sourceAccounts'.
Please change it to:

```
component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts;
```

Full Unit test:

```
describe('MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent', () => {
let component: MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent>;

let source_accounts;

const mockAccountService = {
    accountNameUpdated$: of({
        accountId: '123465',
        newAccountName: 'name',
    }),
};

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent,
        ],
        imports: [
            TranslateModule.forRoot(),
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            FormsModule,
            IonicModule,
        ],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: AccountService,
                useValue: mockAccountService,
            },
        ],
    }).compileComponents();

    source_accounts = [
        {
            id: 'USD3041',
            name: 'Deposit_Account1',
            balance: 'US$ 482,610.41 cr',
            accountno: '00003041',
            currency: {
                id: 'USD',
                symbol: 'US$',
            },
        },
        {
            id: 'GBP4041',
            name: 'Current_Account4',
            balance: '£ 482.00 cr',
            accountno: '00005041',
            currency: {
                id: 'GBP',
                symbol: '£',
            },
        },
    ] as Array<IObject>;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(
        MoneyVouchersPurchaseComponent
    );

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.sourceAccounts = source_accounts;

    fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});